# How to use MasterPage for WebPage in SubDirectory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, master-pages

### Parser Error or Master Page error?

[image: Parser Error Picture]

I have a website with a MasterPage in my Visual Studio 2010 project.

I have many WebForms located in SubDirectories, but for this question I will focus on the SubDirectory called **/contact**.

In VS2010, all of the WebForms in the **/contact** directory display as they are supposed to using this page directive code:

```
<%@ MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" ... %>
```

It is my understanding that the `~/` is supposed to direct the page to the root folder.

Yet, when I go to a page in that folder, I get a Parser Error saying that the MasterPage does not exist because the page is attempting to load the MasterPage from here:

> '/contact/Site.Master'

If I modify my VS2010 project so that the page directive tries to step back to the root level, the VS project give me Master Page errors.

Does not work:

```
<%@ MasterPageFile="../~/Site.Master" ... %>
```

Also does not work:

```
<%@ MasterPageFile="~/../Site.Master" ... %>
```

[image: Master Page error]

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something is probably wrong in the visualstdio at your end.

I am pretty sure what you are doing is correct.

I just tried creating an asp.net project,
added a folder called contact and then dragged a default.aspx page inside it

this is code in the markup file

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Here is the folder structure.

Every things works at my end.
[image]

BTW if you were indeed trying to read  masterpage from a page in contact folder and the framework somehow looks inside contact as the root then try

> ../Site.Master

Comment: I may have **'/contact'** setup as a local root in IIS (can't remember). Let me try `../Site.Master`. HA! VS2010 did not complain, but the webpage **Parser Error Message:**  *The virtual path '/Site.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.* OK, I need to find out how to unset it as an application root. Thanks!